# How can i prompt users to input values into dictionary keys: name, age, course and print the value in a tabular form using python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key, user-input

I want to write a code where by the code will ask users to input value into the following keys;
Name, Age, Course.

Note that the space for user input can be between 1 and 20.

Then I will be able to print the keys and the values EVEN IF the users input is not up to 20 but did not exceed 20 users

Comment: Okay so try something first, then if you encounter an issue with your code, post your code and issue here. If you have no idea where to start then you should do some tutorials, this site isn't a place to have people write all your code for you or teach you the absolute basics.

Comment: Looks like Homework!!

Comment: [It's okay to ask homework questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/8805293) However, as the link states: **Make** **a** **good** **faith** **attempt** **to** **solve** **the** **problem** **yourself** **first**. This will make it more likely you will get a better answer if you show your "progress" into solving it yourself.

Comment: I have already wrote my code to the extent of accepting only single user's input. But why I did not add it is because I'm having difficulty posting my codes here as I am a beginner on this stackoverflow

Comment: @AdeyinkaAzeez Copy the code and paste it into the editor of the question. Then, inside of the editor, highlight the code and press `ctrl+k`. That should format the code into it's own code-block. You can read more about code-formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: //
student = {}

name = input('please enter your name: ')
age= input('please enter your age: ')
Course = input('please enter your course: ')


details = [name, age, course]
student[0] = details

print('{:<10} {:<10} {:<10}'.format('NAME', 'AGE', 'COURSE'))

for key, value in student.items():
    name, age, course = value
    print('{:<10} {:<10} {<10}'.format(name, age, course))

Comment: @AdeyinkaAzeez code goes into your question, never in comments

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to acomplish here exactly. The following codes
creates a dictionary with all the information as keys.

```
user_dict={}
counter=1
while True:
    print ("Enter data for user: ",counter)
    name= input("enter name")
    age = input("enter age")
    course = input("enter course")
    user_dict[(name,age,course)]=counter
    choice  = input("do you want to continue y:yes/press any other key to quit")
    if choice=="y" or choice=="Y":
        break
```

If you want to check if a person of a specific age has taken a course, just do

```
print (("daniel","20","Data Structures") in user_dict)
```